# Trimming a string in a list

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list that contains string values.  I need to trim the leading and ending values.  Here is the code:

```
        using EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp;
        public List<FTPFile> FileList = new List<FTPFile>();

        FTP = new FTPConnection() { ServerAddress = _host, UserName = _user, Password = _password };
        FTP.Connect();
        FTP.TransferType = FTPTransferType.BINARY;
        FTP.ChangeWorkingDirectory(_as400_directory);
        FTP.LocalDirectory = _local_directory;
        FileList.AddRange(FTP.GetFileInfos());
        FTP.Close();
```

The FileList list contains following example values:

```
test 123 11/01/12 *STMF File1.csv somegarbagevalues
test 123 11/01/12 *STMF File2.csv somegarbagevalues
test 123 11/01/12 *STMF File3.csv somegarbagevalues
```

What I need to do is capture online the file name (ex. File1.csv, File2.csv ...) Is there a way to trim the unwanted values without looping through the list or trim when I do the FileList.AddRange statement?

Comment: It looks like the API returns a list of rich objects, so why don't you just use the Name property? See http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/doc/api/EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp.FTPFileMembers.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ makes this easy:

```
FileList.AddRange(FTP.GetFileInfos().Select(x => x.Trim()));
```

where `Trim()` would be a method (possibly an extension method) on `FTPFile` which returned an `FTPFile` with trimmed filename.

Comment: how about instead of doing a trim, I want to select the filename property that is returned from FTPFile in GetFileInfos()?  Or do I have to loop through FTPFile?

Comment: @Nick: It depends on what you need - I assumed that as you had a variable of type `List<FTPFile>`, that you needed that. *Something's* going to have to loop, whether that's explicit in your code or in LINQ. It's not really clear what you need to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

FTPFile is a class and has a property "Name". You were probably looking at the ToString() implementation of the FTPFile class that gave you all the properties at once.

See:
http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/doc/api/EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp.FTPFileMembers.html

Just use:

```
 foreach(FTPFile f in FileList)
 {
     string name = f.Name;
     // Do whatever you want with name.

 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyway to access name in the existing FileList i'm creating? Or do I create a new list and add it into new list as I'm looping. `FileList.AddRange(FTP.GetFileInfos()); foreach (FTPFile f in FileList) { string name = f.Name; }`

Comment: Just use:
    var stringList = new List<string>();
    stringList.AddRange(FileList.Select(f => f.Name));